# How can VNC Server still work while doing windows updates?

Tags: windows, server, vnc

I installed "VNC Server" on a VM, and then I had to start some windows updates (you know...) and I could still see the percentage of the updates while installing.

But how? There should be no processes anymore in the background.

Comment: What vnc server do you use?

Comment: @dan1st VNC Connect/VNC Server from realvnc.com

Comment: If you find it difficult to tag a question with a programming language, it's probably off-topic. This one certainly is.

Comment: @IInspectable Stackoverflow is for questions about programming and programming tools. You may consider RealVNC as a programming tool but you can argue about that.

Comment: Ok. What programming language?